# Javascript Unordered list Onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an unordered list in the html to which I have append list items using javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/GetSchools",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.Items, function (index, value) {
                console.log("the schoolname is" + value.schoolName);
                $('ul#dropdown-items').append(' <li role="presentation"><a id="value.schoolId" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" onclick="setschool(this.id);return false;">value.schoolName</a></li>');
                $('ul#dropdown-items').append('<li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I couldn't get value.schoolName and onclick="setschool(this.id); working..

Comment: The code that appends to the ul is working, perhaps you are getting bad data from the ajax call or you are doing further processing which is breaking things.  Or maybe the setschool function is invalid and not linking up.  http://jsbin.com/aXUgemA/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/AXm7d/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    i=0;
    value=["Hello","hi","hey"];
    $.each(value,function(){
        $('#dropdown-items').append("<li  > <a   style='cursor:pointer' id='"+value[i]+"'>"+value[i]+"</a></li><br/>");
        i++;
    });

    $("a").on("click",function(){
    alert(this.id);
    });
    });
```

Comment: Hi Vignesh tahnks for reply.. but the problem now is with onclick...which I couldn't get working

Comment: thanks for reply vignesh.. ur solution can be considered as a work-around and Im accepting it. Though accessing "a" tag generically from jquery doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are hardcoding the value as a string, not a variable.  When you inspect the page, did it print the id's correctly?

Note: one thing you also want to keep in mind is to **NOT** use a number for an element id, instead have it written like this: `<a id="school_101">Graystone High</a>`

This is how you can achieve everything:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetSchools",
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data.Items, function (index, value) {
                            console.log("the schoolname is" + value.schoolName);
                            $('ul#dropdown-items').append(' <li role="presentation"><a id="school_'+value.schoolId+'" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" onclick="setschool(this.id);return false;">'+value.schoolName+'</a></li>');
                        });
                     }
                });
           });
```

Also, I noticed you added append 2 items: one contains the data, while the other acts as a separator.  You use one `<li>` and check to see if that element is the last of the data-set.  If it is **not** the last one, you can give it a style of `border-bottom: 1px dashed #CCC`.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply... Now Im able to populate the list but.. onclick doesn't work yet.. I get setschool is not defined